# suggestion on workflow and tools to work with node.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, workflow, read-eval-print-loop

I'm developing some really simple node.js libraries for learning purposes.

It's about functions like HexToBase64 and things like that.

Ideally, I'd like to program in a text editor, and play with it on the node repl, having the code automatically reloaded on the repl on every save.

Any module or tool to interactively play with node?

Answer (score 1):

There are modules such as [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor), [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) that can reload your application on a code change. Otherwise, you can create your own implementation like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  var worker = cluster.fork();

  fs.watch(process.argv[1], function(event, filename) {
    worker.kill();
    worker = cluster.fork();
  });
}

if (cluster.isWorker) {
  // put your application logic here that will
  // run when this file changes
}
```

As for using Node interactively, you can just run `node` in a terminal and you have an interactive console. If you needed to load a script and use it interactively, then you would use `.load script.js`.

Comment: yes, when dealing with a web app I use nodemon, I was just wondering if there's something that would automatically run the .load statement when working from the repl

Comment: Under what conditions? On application startup? You could probably manage something of the sort with a bash script or batch file.

Comment: the reload should fire whenever the file is saved. I guess it's a pretty common scenario, do you know of any plugin that could handle something like that?

Comment: You can use the native REPL module and create an interface. Since you can set the input stream for REPL like this: `repl.start({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});` you can write the `.load` statement to the input stream or something of the sort.